# Maximum significance level

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

What is the **maximum significance level** that the null hypothesis is not rejected?

How do I calculate it?

Context:

The weight of a plate is a normally distributed variable with μ=330 gr. and standard deviation σ=5 gr. A sample of 25 plates has a mean weight of 333 gr. Given that the variance is σ^2=25, test the hypothesis that the population mean has increased (or it has remained the same), with a significance level of 10 %. What is the maximum significance level that the null hypothesis is not rejected?

Comment: You don't.  You specify it.  Perhaps you should review material on hypothesis tests and p-values.  We have some good threads: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests for instance.

Comment: Please offer some of the context that led to your question. (Are you perhaps asking about a p-value?)